# Hide all columns except the one which has a header matching a specific cell value

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2013

I want to see data of the only branch which I selected in C2, except all remain hidden. I have different branches' data e.g. ABT, BWP, and SWL. In cell C2 I have made a drop-down list by using the data-validation option now I want to link the C2 cell with this and want only branch data that I selected in the C2 cell. I am sharing pictures of my worksheet. Please guide.

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJ9SI.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

That's hard to do, so instead, do something easy to get the same result:

Insert a column between F and G. In F5 you want to find the right column and fetch the data from there. Something like:

```
=INDEX($H$5:$ZZ$999,,MATCH($C$2,$H$4:$ZZ$4,0))
```

Adjust the ZZ to the last column which represents a branch, and note column H is what used to be G. Copy formula down as far as it goes.
You might consider moving the drop-down data validation to G4 so it labels the column properly, or using =$C$2 in that cell (note: neither of these is a good idea if you convert the data range to a Table).

Now you just hide all the branch columns, or maybe for preference you group them (from the Data tab of the ribbon) so it is easier to hide / reveal them at will.
Pick a branch, it gets the data and displays only that column, while the others remain hidden. Job done.